STM32 timer interrupts are never firing
I'm working with an STM32 Nucleo board and trying to get timer interrupts working. I have a breakpoint set in the ISR but it's never being reached. I'm finding it difficult to understand the HAL documentation but I've been trying for weeks and I can't get this simple program to work. Is there anything that is standing out as obviously incorrect?
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_def.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_cortex.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f7xx.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_conf.h"
#include "stm32f722xx.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_dma.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_rcc_ex.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal_tim.h"
#define LED_PIN GPIO_PIN_7
#define LED_PORT GPIOB

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim;

void main(void) {
    HAL_StatusTypeDef h = HAL_Init();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
    htim.Instance = TIM2;
    htim.Init.Prescaler = SystemCoreClock / 1000 - 1;
    htim.Init.Period = 1000;
    htim.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
    HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(&htim);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim);
    HAL_TIM_RegisterCallback(&htim, HAL_TIM_PERIOD_ELAPSED_CB_ID, HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim);

    while(1) {}
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim) {
    int i = 1;
}

I've tried all sorts of examples from various forum answers and the HAL documentation

The code doesn't call SystemClock_Config() so I'm suspicious that the clocks are not setup correctly.  Have you tried the TIM examples for your board in the STM32CubeF7 package?  Have you tried generating your project from STM32CubeMX?

do not touch pririties.

TIM2 is 32bit. You want to wait more than 2^32 clocks for the interrupt. If you did not change the clock settings then you run on 4MHz clock and overflow will occur every 1073.74182375 seconds. Did you wait so long?
